# using phpmailer with plesk smtp

Tags: php, wordpress, email, phpmailer, plesk

I'm trying to setup PHP mailer on my VPS with Plesk SMTP.

**The PHP code**

```
require("path_to_phpmailer");
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                            
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
    $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array (
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'  => true,
        'verify_depth' => 3,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'peer_name' => 'Plesk',
        )
    );
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'support@mywebsite.com';
    $mail->Password = 'somepassword';
    $mail->setFrom('support@mywebsite.com', 'Name Surname');
    $mail->addAddress('someadress@web.de', 'Name Surname');
    $mail->Subject = 'Email subject';
    $mail->msgHTML('Email content with <strong>html</strong>');
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }

        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

support@mywebsite.com is the email that i created in my ples dashboard and somepassword is its password. However running the script gives the following output:

```
2018-04-14 09:27:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 myserver.net ESMTP 
Postfix (Ubuntu)
2018-04-14 09:27:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mywebsite.com
2018-04-14 09:27:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-myserver.net250- 
PIPELINING250-SIZE 10240000250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 
PLAIN LOGIN250-XFORWARD NAME ADDR PROTO HELO SOURCE PORT IDENT250- 
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
2018-04-14 09:27:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-04-14 09:27:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-04-14 09:27:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-04-14 09:27:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-04-14 09:27:10 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/TroubleshootingMessage has been 
sent
```

Did I understand something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're using TLS to localhost - and the certificate the mail server publishes will never match that name, which will be why you're getting that error. Since it's localhost, there's no point in encrypting anyway, but if you're getting it automatically because of autotls you can either disable that or use the name that *does* appear on the mail server's certificate, which presumably will map to the same location.

Comment: thank you! I found a workaround using a mail api. Using no encryption i was able to call the phpmailer functions without an error, but for some reason the mail was still not send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if is a problem with ssl, and try again

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
   'ssl' => array(
   'verify_peer' => false,
   'verify_peer_name' => false,
   'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
);
```

if it still has an error

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Comment: This isn't a solution, it's hiding the error rather than fixing the problem - we already know that it's a TLS problem because it matches one of the exact circumstances described in the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Try add *cafile*. Should help  [PHPMailer ssl_options.phps](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/ssl_options.phps)